# GCP External load balancer - Choose another backend for retrying

Tags: load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

I have two internet backend services and configured as `weightedBackendServices` in the `urlMap`. How can I configure application loadbalancer to retry with another backend service when retrying ?

Any alternative ?